# How to add popup component in JTextField

Tags: java, swing

I want to add component into JTextField as a popup like this.

[alt text http://img502.imageshack.us/img502/3688/popupsample.png](http://img502.imageshack.us/img502/3688/popupsample.png)

i want to add  my component for example JPanel...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a `JPopupMenu` -- launched via your button and placed relative to your text field:

```
final JTextField textField = ...
JButton button = ...
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
        popup.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        popup.add(new JPanel()); // your component
        popup.setPopupSize(100, 100);
        popup.show(textField, 0, textField.getHeight());
    }
});
```